# call destroy method from withing html using link_to :method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to rails, I'm watching a older tutorial series based on rails 3 and I'm trying call the destroy method using `link_to`  `<%=link_to("Delete Post", @post, :method => :delete)%>` I'm assuming is has changed in rails 4 but I have not been able to find a way to do it?

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Myrubyblog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%flash.each do |key,value|%>
    <p><%=value%></p>
<%end%>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you tried it? It should work in Rails 4 as well.

Comment: It works exactly the same in Rails 4. However this uses the rails unobstructive javascript driver to fake a form submission so that the request appears to be a DELETE request. If there are any script errors preventing `jquery_ujs` from doing its job the request is just sent as a plain GET request just like any other link. Look at the browser console for errors.

Comment: You can also use `button_to("Delete Post", @post, method: :delete)` which does not rely on javascript.

Comment: yes i tried it, it just links to the current page and does nothing else.

Comment: im getting these errors `GET http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/default.css`
 `GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/default.js ` I will use `button_to` if I have to but I would like to get `link_to` to work.

Comment: add the path so you know exactly where you are going, i.e.: link_to (or button_to)  link_to post_path(@post), method: :delete

Comment: I'm using `redirect_to` within the destroy method.

Comment: @CarsonCole, that makes no sense and is not even the correct call signature for `link_to` which he is using correctly. Its `link_to("text", @thing, { option: 1 })`

Comment: @glencashen add your `views/layouts/application.html.erb` to the question. You may also wan't to check the rails log after you click as well. It will tell you exactly what http method was used and what controller was called.

Comment: Do you have a `app/assets/javascripts/default.js` and `app/assets/stylesheets/default.css`? When you generate a rails app the default names of the assets are `application.js` and `application.css`.

Comment: is jquery_ujs a part of your bundle?  If so, is it required in `default.js`?